# UltiSnips Latex snippet does not work correctly when wrapped around due to textwidth setting

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-ultisnips, textwidth

Given snippet:

```
snippet mm "Inline Math" wA
\\( $1 \\) $0
endsnippet
```

which inserts inline math mode in LaTeX: `\( | \)` where cursor position is `|`

and following .vimrc:

```tex
"-------------Load Plugins------------------
if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
    silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
        \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
    autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
endif
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'lifepillar/vim-mucomplete'
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips' | Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'
Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
call plug#end()
"---------------End Plugins added-----------------------
"----------- UltiSnips triggering-------------
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger = '<C-a>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger = '<C-a>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger = '<C-d>'
let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=[$HOME.'/.vim/UltiSnips']
"-----------End ultisnips--------------------
"---------Begin MuComplete Setup-----------
  set completeopt+=menuone
  set completeopt+=noselect
  set belloff+=ctrlg
  let g:mucomplete#enable_auto_at_startup = 1
"---------End MuComplete Setup-------------
set textwidth=79
set colorcolumn=79
```

typing `mm` close to column number 79/78 leads to the snippet expansion breaking across two lines.

**Expected behavior:**

If broken into two lines, the snippet should expand like so:

```
\(<col 79>                    <----end of first line
|\)                           <----beginning of next line
```

**Actual behavior:**

instead it expands like so

```
\(<col 79>                    <----end of first line
\|)                           <----beginning of next line
```

where the cursor position after snippet expansion is between the closing `\` and `)`

Is there a way to fix this within UltiSnips so that it expands across broken lines just as it would expand within the same line?

Explanatory animated gif below:

[image]

Comment: linked github issue: https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/1510

Comment: @husB Yes indeed. I had originally posted it in VimTeX repo and the author suggested to ask over at the github page of UltiSnips -- which seems a bit quiet to be honest. Hence my post here in the hope of trying to fix this issue!

Comment: Indeed it is, the maintainer has been very busy for the past 2 years, unfortunately. Anyway, is this issue related to latex, or does it also occur for a snippet that gets expanded at the end of the line?